# Error in C:\Users\user\Downloads\question2.asm line 12 column 2: "lui": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: lui $t1,100

Tags: mips

[MIPS assembly language error type. The code does not rum unless these problems are fixed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMcKq.png)

Comment: please help urgently

Comment: Don't post images. Show us the code you have and explain your problem (and possibly what have you tried to fix it)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions, or in comments.